# Sequelize: Parent with at least one children

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a relation which is roughly as follows:

```
Parent: [id, name]
Children1: [id, parent_id, name]
Children2: [id, parent_id, name]
Children3: [id, parent_id, name]
Children4: [id, parent_id, name]

Parent 
  .hasMany -> Children1
  .hasMany -> Children2
  .hasMany -> Children3
  .hasMany -> Children4
```

So, if I do:

```
Parent->findOne({
  include: [{model: Children1}, {model: Children2}]
})
```

It will only bring Parent where there's children1 and children2 (ie, Inner join).
If I do:

```
Parent->findOne({
  include: [
    {model: Children1, required: false}, 
    {model: Children2, required: false}
  ]
})
```

It will bring Parent and if there's it will bring Children1 and/or Children2. (ie Left join).

What I want to do is to bring Parent IF AND ONLY IF either Children1 or Children2 or ChildrenN exists. Could be any of the ChildrenN or could be all of them. As long as there's at least 1, I want to bring Parent.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Add `required: true` to your include objects to make each join a right join. Any reason you've got four separate children tables?

Comment: It was just an example, each "Children" is a different table with different shit on it.
So, required: true makes a Right join while the absense of "required" attributes creates Inner join?

Comment: I tried what you said, it still creates an inner join, with required: true

Comment: You know what, I've always had a where clause on my includes when using required true. Maybe that's a requirement. Not at my laptop just now, but I'll check it out when I am.