# Sequelize: require at least one association

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a relation which is roughly as follows:

```
Parent: [id, name]
Children1: [id, parent_id, name]
Children2: [id, parent_id, name]
Children3: [id, parent_id, name]
Children4: [id, parent_id, name]

Parent 
  .hasMany -> Children1
  .hasMany -> Children2
  .hasMany -> Children3
  .hasMany -> Children4
```

So, if I do:

```
Parent->findOne({
  include: [{model: Children1}, {model: Children2}]
})
```

It will only bring Parent where there's children1 and children2 (ie, Inner join). If I do:

```
Parent->findOne({
  include: [
    {model: Children1, required: false}, 
    {model: Children2, required: false}
  ]
})
```

It will bring Parent and if there's it will bring Children1 and/or Children2. (ie Left join).

What I want to do is to bring Parent IF AND ONLY IF either Children1 or Children2 or ChildrenN exists. Could be any of the ChildrenN or could be all of them. As long as there's at least 1, I want to bring Parent.

I copied this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38504835/sequelize-parent-with-at-least-one-children) because this is the same case.

Any ideas?

Comment: If I understand well, did you associate 4 times hasMany(Children)? Why? As far as your explanation goes you only need 1 Model for Children and then just associate once with the model Parent, this you'll have one table with your id, name, parent_id and with just 1 include you'll get the childrens that the parent has.

Answer (score 0):

you need to reverse the logic here, do not define your condition in your include, do it in your where, I resolved my case like this

```
await parentTable.findAll({
where:
  {
    [Op.or]: 
      [
        { '$FirstChildrenTable.id$': { [Op.ne]: null } }, 
        { '$SecondChildrenTable.id$': { [Op.ne]: null } }
     ],
  },
include: 
  [ { model: FirstChildrenTable }, { model: SecondChildrenTable }]
});
```

It could be any field but id (your primaryKey) should be used

Hope it will help some :)